# What are the Autopilot Minimums for a C-172 G1000?

Tags: general-aviation, autopilot, cessna-172, g1000

(GA Pilot)

On a C-172 (G1000 Avionics), what would be the AutoPilot minimums OR at what altitude would one need to disengage the auto-pilot and take controls for:

1) Precision Approaches

2) Non-Precision Approaches

3) Visual Approaches ..?

Comment: Where in the world are you? Approach minima vary around the world...

Comment: As UnrecognizedFallingObject brought up, please edit your question and specify whether you are looking for an answer for an aircraft certified and flown under FAA, EASA, etc. rules as this will change the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Typically, the aircraft flight manual will identify this. In your particular case (Cessna 172 G1000), it is **200 feet AGL** for all approach types.

The C-172 can be fitted with either a Garmin GFC 700, or a Bendix/King KAP 140.

For the GFC 700, it is listed in the aircraft operating limitations:

[image]

In the case of the KAP 140, it is listed in the autopilot supplement:

[image]

Comment: This may vary depending on where the aircraft was certified (the POH is written for the appropriate certifying authority) AND it also varies depending on the regulations....

Comment: That answers my question - thank you!